# How do I typeset units like MB, GB (megabytes, gigabytes)?

Tags: units

Is there a simple way to typeset byte units like MB, GB, TB in latex in math mode? How do you typeset `1GB` for example?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can use [`siunitx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx), which supports both SI and binary prefixes (the latter, via the package option `binary-units`).

You can even define your own units via `\DeclareSIUnit` (though that is not necessary here since binary units are already defined in the library). Its main macro, `\SI`, works in math mode as well as in text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[binary-units]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    For example, $x = \SI{1}{\giga\byte}$ or \SI{1}{\gibi\byte}.
\end{document}
```

See page 38 of [the `siunitx` manual](https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) for further information.

Answer (score 2):

From documentation: "In version 3, the document commands have been revised to be more descriptive. As such, the commands \SI, \SIlist, \SIrange and \si remain available but are not recommended for use in new documents. Use the new \qty... commands instead"

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    For example, \qty{1}{\giga\byte}.
    For example, \qty{50}{\mega\byte}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! BTW, your MWE works (after correcting spelling error) also without `siunitx` option `binary-units` ... can you explain why?