# How to overwrite siunitx's binary prefixes

Tags: siunitx

Is there something special that needs to be done to overwrite a binary prefix using the `siunitx` package? Overriding the SI prefixes is no problem. The MWE with `\sisetup{binary-units=true}` yields:

[image]

but with `\sisetup{binary-units=false}` I obtain:

[image]

Note that I was able to easily redefine `\kilo`, but am unable to redefine `\bit`:

### Reference:

- [How do I typeset units like MB, GB (megabytes, gigabytes)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88848/how-do-i-typeset-units-like-mb-gb-megabytes-gigabytes)

### MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88848/how-do-i-typeset-units-like-mb-gb-megabytes-gigabytes
\sisetup{binary-units=true}%  

\DeclareSIUnit\bit{\textcolor{red}{bit}}%
\DeclareSIUnit\kilo{\textcolor{red}{k}}%

\begin{document}
    \si{\bit}
    \si{\kilo}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the units here are optionally loaded, and as there is a need to allow compatibility with v1, the actual loading is done at the start of the document. Thus you need

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\sisetup{binary-units=true}%  
\AtBeginDocument{
  \DeclareSIUnit\bit{\textcolor{red}{bit}}%
  \DeclareSIUnit\kilo{\textcolor{red}{k}}%
}
\begin{document}
    \si{\bit}
    \si{\kilo}
\end{document}
```