# Detect if a unit is defined with siunitx

Tags: conditionals, siunitx, etoolbox

I am using the `siunitx` pacakge and trying to detect if a unit is defined. My initial assumption was that this would simply be:

```
\ifcsdef{#1}{#1 exists.}{#1 does NOT exist.}
```

This works fine if the unit declaration is *not* deferred until `\AtBeginDocument`.  So, with the units defined as

```
\DeclareSIUnit\milliliter{\textnormal{mL}}%       <--- Can detect this just fine
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \DeclareSIUnit\centiliter{\textnormal{cL}}%   <--- But fails with this?
}%
```

detecting `\milliliter` is fine but detecting `\centiliter` is not so easy.  The MWE below yields:

[image]

### Notes:

- I need to defer some definitions until `\AtBeginDocument` as per
  [How to overwrite siunitx's binary prefixes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287579/how-to-overwrite-siunitxs-binary-prefixes) and would like to have a single method to detect them.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\DeclareSIUnit\milliliter{\textnormal{mL}}%       <--- Can detect this just fine

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \DeclareSIUnit\centiliter{\textnormal{cL}}%   <--- But fails with this?
}

\newcommand*{\TestIfUnitExists}[1]{%
    \par
    \ifcsdef{#1liter}{%
        #1liter exists.
    }{%
        #1liter does NOT exist.
    }%
}%

\begin{document}
    \TestIfUnitExists{giga}%  
    \TestIfUnitExists{milli}% <--- milliliter exists
    \TestIfUnitExists{centi}% <--- centiliter also exists (but test fails)
    \TestIfUnitExists{}%      <--- liter exists as well
\end{document}
```

Comment: What I don't get is why you need to know if they are defined: your preamble should express exactly which units are available.

Comment: @JosephWright: Yes the preamble does express what is avaialble but I have code which typesets text based on an SI prefix and not all SI prefixes are applicable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how the test *ought to* be defined:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\DeclareSIUnit\milliliter{\textnormal{mL}}

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \DeclareSIUnit\centiliter{\textnormal{cL}}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\testifunitexistsTF}{smmm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   { \grill_test_siunit:cTF {#2}{#3}{#4} }
   { \grill_test_siunit:NTF {#2}{#3}{#4} }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \grill_test_siunit:NTF
 {
  \seq_if_in:NnTF \l__siunitx_declare_list_seq { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \grill_test_siunit:NTF { c }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
  \testifunitexistsTF*{#1liter}{#1liter exists}{#1liter doesn't exist}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{General command}

\texttt{\string\millimeter} \testifunitexistsTF{\milliliter}{exists}{doesn't exist}

\texttt{\string\millimeter} \testifunitexistsTF*{milliliter}{exists}{doesn't exist}

\section{Test}

\test{giga}%

\test{milli}% <--- milliliter exists

\test{centi}% <--- centiliter also exists (but test fails)

\test{}%      <--- liter exists as well

\end{document}
```

[image]

Unfortunately, the sequence variable where all the units are stored is not public, so this cannot be really used. Please, file a feature request to Joseph Wright for making the list of units searchable.

Here's a different implementation, based on another answer, but not typesetting anything in the scope of `\si`. Differently from the previous solution, the macro `\testifunitexists` only accepts a name as argument, not a control sequence.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\DeclareSIUnit\milliliter{\textnormal{mL}}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareSIUnit\centiliter{\textnormal{cL}}%
}

\newtoggle{unitexists}

\newcommand{\testifunitexistsTF}[1]{%
  \global\togglefalse{unitexists}%
  \sbox0{\si{%
    \ifcsdef{#1}{\global\toggletrue{unitexists}}{}%
  }}%
  \iftoggle{unitexists}%
}

\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
  \testifunitexistsTF{#1liter}{#1liter exists}{#1liter doesn't exist}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{General command}

\texttt{\string\millimeter} \testifunitexistsTF{milliliter}{exists}{doesn't exist}

\section{Test}

\test{giga}%

\test{milli}% <--- milliliter exists

\test{centi}% <--- centiliter also exists (but test fails)

\test{}%      <--- liter exists as well

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

The reason for this different behavior seem to be how `siunitx` handles new units that aren't called in the scope of one of the `\si`/`\SI` commands. If we make LaTeX `\show` the definitions immediately after the beginning of the document, we get

```
> \milliliter=\protected\long macro:
->\ERROR .
l.27 \show\milliliter

> \centiliter=undefined.
l.28 \show\centiliter
```

So `\milliliter` is defined to an undefined control sequence, while `\centiliter` is actually undefined, strangely. This additional layer of indirection isn't recognized by your test.

A simple solution is to call your test in the context of the `\si` command when all the new units are in scope:

```
\newcommand*{\TestIfUnitExists}[1]{%
    \par
    \si{%
        \ifcsdef{#1liter}{%
            #1liter exists.
        }{%
            #1liter does NOT exist.
        }%
    }%
}%
```

[image]

Comment: Great explanation, but for me, the `\si` macro removes the spaces between the words.  Accepting egreg's solution as I think it is better to set a global flag within the `\si` macro.

Answer (score 3):

The defined units are tracked internally by `siunitx` in a sequence. this is *not* public but as your use case seems somewhat odd anyway I guess you might do

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \TestIfUnitExists { m }
  {
    \seq_if_in:NxTF \l__siunitx_declare_list_seq { \exp_not:c { #1 liter } }
      { #1liter~exists. }
      { #1liter~does NOT exist. }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: I'll look at the lack of definition in global scope for `\centiliter` in the question: something not quite right in terms of timing. However, one should _not_ rely on the names being defined in global scope: this is only done as it's required by the `s`-type column, and to be honest with hindsight that was not a great plan. (If/when I finish v3 I'll likely not make that available as-standard.)